# Can I associate two or more Web ACLs (WAF) to a single Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

So, in Cloudfront in the console (web ui), when creating a distribution there is a dropbox for the WAF we want to assign to it. But if I want to assign it with a second one, it replaces the first one.

In the documentation, I haven't found explicitly that assigning 2 WAFs is not possible. So is there a way I can achieve this maybe using `awscli` or any other method?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't associate more than one Web ACLs to the CloudFront distribution. However, you can put all the rules into one and associate that ACL with the CF distribution if possible.

Comment: I'd have liked a valid source for this answer (like an amazon doc or video), but I guess that is hard to found (if even exist).
However the idea is good, to put all rules in the WebACL, thanks.

Comment: From this [Amazon document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-associating-aws-resource.html) : "You can associate each AWS resource with only one web ACL. The relationship between web ACL and AWS resources is one-to-many. " @IvanCarcamo

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't associate multiple Web ACL to a resource type (eg: cloudfront/API Gateway etc).

> Restrictions on multiple associations
>
> You can associate a single web ACL with one or more AWS resources,
> according to the following restrictions:
>
> You can associate each AWS resource with only one web ACL. The
> relationship between web ACL and AWS resources is one-to-many.
>
> You can associate a web ACL with one or more CloudFront distributions.
> You can't associate a web ACL that you've associated with a CloudFront
> distribution with any other AWS resource type.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-associating-aws-resource.html